# Eclipse - failure to find parent pom, but maven build actually works from Eclipse itself

Tags: eclipse, maven, repository, parent-pom, dependency-resolution

Eclipse keeps telling me it can't find the parent pom of my project, but if I run `mvn -U install` on my project, from Eclipse, the build works.

I'm using Eclipse Neon.1 Release (4.6.1), and configured it to use my external maven, which is maven 3.3.9.

This is the exact marker that Eclipse shows me:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for nl.travelcard.common:tc-parent-fuse:2.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find nl.travelcard.common:tc-parent:pom:12 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

And this is the parent tag in my pom:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>tc-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>nl.travelcard.common</groupId>
    <version>12</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Are you sure your parent dep are available in maven central, because i can't find it http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cnl.travelcard.common

Comment: It's not. It's in our nexus server, which is configured already in my settings.xml, and maven CAN find it, as the maven build actually works. From Eclipse and from the command line. That's what's weird about the whole thing.

Comment: have you configured this 2 things in Eclipse: Window -> preferences -> Maven -> installations and had your own maven distrib. And also Window->Preferences->Maven->User Settings and had in global settings the settings file currently used by your own maven distrib ?

Comment: I hadn't set the global settings, no. But setting it to the default one, /conf/settings.xml seems to have triggered Eclipse to realise there's no problem with the maven build. So the markers are gone now, go figure.

Thanks for the help, @colin. If you want to create an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure that Eclipse uses the same maven distribution with the same configuration as you in a shell, you have to configure 2 things in Eclipse:

- In Windows->Preference->Maven->Installations you have to add your own maven distribution.
- In Windows->Preference->Maven->User Settings you have to add in global settings the same file used by your local maven distrib.